# MySql - RegEx extract variable sequence of number

Tags: mysql, regex

I do have this table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2_sim;
CREATE TABLE test2_sim (
texto VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
);
```

with this records:

```
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/A/posts/2088973241125818');
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/A/posts/2088973241125818?commen');
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/B/posts/10155759853867175?__xts_');
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/C/posts/595673157521288');
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/D/posts/365108183946?__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARCs');
INSERT INTO test2_sim (texto) VALUES ('/E/posts/1028007200735853?__xts__%5B0%5');
```

I'm trying to extract for each record the variable sequence of numbers,
for example

```
Record1 > 2088973241125818
Record2 > 2088973241125818
Record3 > 10155759853867175
```

Is it possible to use REGEX command in the Select statements?
like:

```
Select *, REGEX(texto,'^[specific_patterns]' AS regex_out from test2_sim;
```

Let's suppose a valid sequence of number are consecutive digits>10.

Thanks a lot
Regs

Comment: "Is it possible to use REGEX command in the Select statements? like:" Upgrade to MySQL 8,0 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

Comment: "Let's suppose a valid sequence of number are consecutive digits>10." What do you mean here?

Comment: what is the version of your mysql?

Comment: MySQL Version is 5.6.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `REGEX`. What about this way using `CONVERT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX`?

```
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(texto, '/', -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) as seq_num from test2_sim;
```

**See fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e914d/12

Comment: +1 Yes offcource `SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)` also allows negative numbers to do a "backtracking" search from the end from the string to the `/` char which it returns.. Sometimes you forgot some features.

Comment: Yes, sir. agreed. I also forgot something every day :). Thanks!

Comment: "I also forgot something every day" it's bad that means you learn something new every day more or less

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you!

Comment: @RaymondNijland exactly sir. Learning new things is my strength :)

Answer (score 1):

This query shows you how the "parse" the number without use REGEX.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , CAST(
     REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            REVERSE(texto)
          , '/'
          , 1
        )
     ) AS UNSIGNED)
FROM 
 test2_sim
```

**Result**

```
| texto                                        | CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(texto), '/', 1)) AS UNSIGNED) |
| -------------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| /A/posts/2088973241125818                    | 2088973241125818                                                   |
| /A/posts/2088973241125818?commen             | 2088973241125818                                                   |
| /B/posts/10155759853867175?__xts_            | 10155759853867175                                                  |
| /C/posts/595673157521288                     | 595673157521288                                                    |
| /D/posts/365108183946?__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARCs | 365108183946                                                       |
| /E/posts/1028007200735853?__xts__%5B0%5      | 1028007200735853                                                   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4uxib6SVNg7pa78M6CJMRA/0)